# Latex: vertically center an image in a subfigure

Tags: centering, subfigure

I am trying to put two pictures together in a subfigure and minipage environment. What I am seeking for is to have the two figures vertically centered with each other (the smaller figure has to be centered, not at the bottom as it usually happens). I have reached this goal, however, the big figure (figure b) seems to overlap its subcaption. How can I solve this issue (without making the figure smaller)?

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: To prevent overlapping, set width=\columnwidth in the \includegraphics options. This will reduce the figure size though. Dont' see a way around that - unless you use landscape mode or something